# Options not being posted by Bootstrap Multiselect

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-multiselect

I'm using Bootstrap Multiselect (https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect). It's a great component but i'm having the issue described below.

Let's say i have a select with id 'select-status' with 10 options and i want the app opens by default with the first 3 options selected. For this i'm using this code :

```
$(function () {
    $('#select-status').multiselect('select','1');
    $('#select-status').multiselect('select','2');
    $('#select-status').multiselect('select','3');
});
```

I can see the code above works because the 3 options appear checked when i load my application.

The problem is, when i submit the form, only one option is being posted, UNLESS i manually click on the select dropdown to show the options. Only by doing this and not even clicking in any option, the form will post correctly, with the 3 selected options.

I assume that probably i need to do some code after i select the options programatically.

Any hints ?

Thanks !

Comment: I assume the last value checked is the one being posted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you use an array of values instead?

```
$('#select-status').multiselect('select', ['1', '2', '3']);
```

It would be interesting to see the rest of your markup too, though. And also hear what you use to grab the data.

Comment: Yep, http://davidstutz.de/bootstrap-multiselect/#methods It accepts array as well.

Comment: By doing so the same result occurs ; it works on the screen, but post only the last value (3 in the case), unless i manually open the dropdown before submit the form.

Comment: Maybe is there a command that open and closes the dropdown programatically, so i can simulate what i'm doing manually ?

Comment: Please update your post showing us what the html-markup looks like, how you post the values (normal form submission or a javascript?) and explain how you receive those values. Is it a PHP script?